# Autohotkey How can I do multiple imageSearches using a function parameter

Tags: function, scripting, autohotkey

I am trying to use imagesearch to buy certain items from an item shop in a game. There are 8 slots therefore I need to loop it 8 times. There are 4-5 different items I need to buy if they appear.

This is the function I use to do the buying:

```
marketFunc(item)
{
    Loop, 8
    {
        ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, item
        if !ErrorLevel
        {
            outY = %OutputVarY%
            outY += 119
            MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
            Sleep, 250
            Click
            Sleep, 750
            MouseClick, left,  797,  456
            Sleep, 750
            MouseClick, left,  687,  473
            Sleep, 100
        }
        Sleep, 250
    }
}
```

I've then been calling the function like this:

```
marketfunc(chip.png)
sleep, 500
marketfunc(ticket.png)
sleep, 500
marketfunc(scroll.png)
sleep, 500
marketfunc(masterScroll.png)
sleep, 500
marketfunc(otherItemHere.png)
```

I know I can do it without the function like this:

```
Loop, 8
{
    ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, ticket.png
    if !ErrorLevel
    {
        outY = %OutputVarY%
        outY += 119
        MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
        Sleep, 250
        Click
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  797,  456
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  687,  473
        Sleep, 100

    }
    Sleep, 250

    ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, chip.png
    if !ErrorLevel
    {
        outY = %OutputVarY%
        outY += 119
        MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
        Sleep, 250
        Click
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  797,  456
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  687,  473
        Sleep, 100

    }
    Sleep, 250

    ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, scroll.png
    if !ErrorLevel
    {
        outY = %OutputVarY%
        outY += 119
        MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
        Sleep, 250
        Click
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  797,  456
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  687,  473
        Sleep, 100

    }
    Sleep, 250

    ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, masterScroll.png
    if !ErrorLevel
    {
        outY = %OutputVarY%
        outY += 119
        MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
        Sleep, 250
        Click
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  797,  456
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  687,  473
        Sleep, 100

    }
    Sleep, 250

    ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, otherItemHere.png
    if !ErrorLevel
    {
        outY = %OutputVarY%
        outY += 119
        MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
        Sleep, 250
        Click
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  797,  456
        Sleep, 750
        MouseClick, left,  687,  473
        Sleep, 100

    }
    Sleep, 250
}
```

But I don't like the looks of it, and it feels too hard code-y.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention what the actual issue was. When I run it, it does not find the images when I use my function method. However when I do it using the example below it works fine. So I assume I've set the function parameters wrong somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use an array for this:

```
Array := [Item1, Item2, ..., ItemN]
```

or in your case

```
Images := ["chip.png", "ticket.png", "basicScroll.png", "heroicScroll.png"]
```

Then you could loop over that array and use the value at the index instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind got it to work.

```
    marketFunc("chip.png")
    marketFunc("ticket.png")
    marketFunc("basicScroll.png")
    marketFunc("heroicScroll.png")


marketFunc(item)
{
    Loop, 8
    {
        ImageSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 0, 0, %A_ScreenWidth%, %A_ScreenHeight%, %item%
        if !ErrorLevel
        {
            outY = %OutputVarY%
            outY += 119
            MouseMove, %OutputVarX%, %OutY%
            Sleep, 250
;           Click
            Sleep, 750
;           MouseClick, left,  797,  456
            Sleep, 750
;           MouseClick, left,  687,  473
            Sleep, 100

        }
        Sleep, 250

    }
}
```